# ExitNodes not respected on particular website

Tags: exit-relays, location

**I have**

```
ExitNodes {rs},{kr},{sy},{cn}
StrictNodes 1
```

**set in my `./Browser/TorBrowser/Data/Tor/torrc` file. It respects these ExitNodes on every website I've tried:**

[image]

**except this website where it switches between nodes not on my list:**

[image]

**It used to work fine on this website. I recently updated to Tor Browser 10.0.2. I tried on Stander and Safer, but haven't made any other configuration changes.**

Comment: `StrictNodes` doesn't help here. If you are setting `ExitNodes` but Tor is choosing circuits with exit nodes outside of those, then you should file a bug on Tor's Gitlab site.

Comment: https://gitlab.torproject.org/tpo/core/tor/-/issues/40167